# What am I doing wrong with a:hover?

Tags: css

This is the CSS code I have that isn't working:

```
h2 a:link, h2 a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
font-size:14pt;
font-weight:100;
color:#000;
}

h2 a:hover; {
text-decoration: none;
font-size:14pt;
font-weight:100;
color:#909090;
}
```

Why doesn't the hover part work? What am I doing wrong? I'm new to CSS.

Comment: Spend a little more time reading over your code. I know typos are annoying but you have a very simple one there (and based on your working code you know it is incorrect).

Comment: There's a semicolon after the a:hover that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 5):

change the css rule "a:hover;" to "a:hover"

ie: remove the ;

Answer (score 0):

You have an semicolon before the opening curly brace for `a:hover`, so change it to:

```
h2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:14pt;
  font-weight:100;
  color:#909090;
}
```

Comment: `;` is a semicolon. An asterisk is `*`.

Answer (score -1):

While you're at it, combine common rules.

```
h2 a:link, 
h2 a:visited,
h2 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:14pt;
    font-weight:100;
}

h2 a:link, 
h2 a:visited {
    color:#000;
}

h2 a:hover; {
    color:#909090;
}
```